# Inverse power of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $x_n$ is a sequence of real such that ${x_n}^3$ has a convergent sequence ${x_{k_n}}^3$ then can we say that $x_{k_n}$ is a convergent sequence of the original sequence ?

I was thinking that inverse cube will always have a real root so this might be true.

Any insight. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is trivially true. $\sqrt[3]{x} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function; so it commutes with limits. So if $x_{k(n)}^3 \to L$ (say), then
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{k(n)} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[3]{x_{k(n)}^3} = \sqrt[3]{\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{k(n)}^3} = \sqrt[3]{L}
$$

Comment: Yeah ! Thanks I get it now

Comment: @hiren_garai Hello, if my answer successfully tackles your question, consider accepting it.

Comment: I have one query. Is $x \to x^{1/p}$ for $ p \neq 0$ is always continuous when domain and range is real ?

Comment: @hiren_garai The even powers $p$ causes problems. E.g. if $p = 2$, then $x^{1/2} = \sqrt{x}$ may be continuous BUT it is *not even defined* for negative $x$. Similar issues arise if say $p$ is irrational.

Comment: Got your point. Thanks